# How to change datetime intervals in Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, formtastic

Formtastic currently automatically creates a range of 1..59 for datetime inputs.

But what if I wanted the datetime minute options to be 0, 15, 30, 45?

Is there a way I can set the collection for a datetime in Formastic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `:minute_step => 15` option, for example:

```
<%= form.input :created_at, :minute_step => 15 %>
```

Look at [select_minute Rails method docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_minute) and [time_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select).

Looks like Formtastic uses Rails `select_*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful

https://github.com/tamoyal/simple_time_select